# CMake Android NDK error armeabi-v7a on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, cmake, android-ndk

I try to compile a shared library on Ubuntu using CMake for Android
my "toolchain.cmake" file :

```
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 26)
set (CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI armeabi-v7a)
set (CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "/home/user/android-ndk-r23b")
set (CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE c++_shared)
```

but I have this message error :

> Android: The API specified by CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION='26' does not exist in the NDK. The directory: /home/user/android-ndk-r23b/platforms/android-26 does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: `gnustl_static` <-- That STL implementation was removed from the NDK a long time ago (in r18b).

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message it seems that the path /home/user/android-ndk-r23b/platforms/android-26 does not exist. You can download the NDK from here https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads and create and validate the path  /home/user/android-ndk-r23b/platforms/android-26 from hand.